# Python: Global name 'info' is not defined

Tags: python, string

Buen día, realmente yo no tengo taaaanta experiencia programando en Python (Soy un estudiante, en realidad) lo que pasa es lo siguiente: Tengo una asignacion en la que debo de poner en practica el uso de listas enlazadas, creando nodos.

Y pues eso, creo los nodos con una clase definida para ellos y les agrego valores, pero a la hora de imprimirlos me arroja el siguiente error:

> Traceback(Most recent call last): File "clase.py", line 62, in
>    print(c.getInfo()) File "clase.py", line 24, in getInfo
>   return str(info.getTitulo()) NameError: Global Name 'info' is not
>   defined

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
class Nodo():
    def __init__(self,pos):
        siguiente = ''
        self.pos = pos
        elemento = ''
        info = NodoInfo(self.pos)

    def getSiguiente(self):
        return self.siguiente

    def setSiguiente(self,n):
        self.siguiente = n

    def getPos(self):
        return pos

    def setElemento(self,a):
         elemento = a

    def getElemento(self):
        return elemento

    def getInfo(self):
        return str(info.getTitulo())

class NodoInfo():
    def __init__(self,pos):
        self.titulo = "Numero de nodo: "+str(pos)
        self.desc = "Este nodo puede almacenar datos."
        self.detalle = "Especificamente, almacena datos de tipo Object (Amplio espectro de TDA's)."

    def getTitulo(self):
        return self.titulo

    def getDesc(self):
        return self.desc

    def getDetalle(self):
        return self.detalle

pos = 1
seguir = 1
n = Nodo(pos)
c = Nodo(pos)

x = raw_input("Ingrese su primer dato: ")
n.setElemento(x)
while(seguir):
    pos = pos + 1
    opc = raw_input("Desea ingresar otro dato? S/N ")
    if(opc == 'S'):
        a = Nodo(pos)
        n.setSiguiente(a)
        a.setElemento(raw_input("Ingrese el otro dato: "))
        if(c.getSiguiente==''):
            c=n
        n=a
    else:
        seguir = 0

for i in range (1,pos):
    print(c.getInfo())
    print("El nodo almacena: "+c.getElemento())
```

Les agradeceria su ayuda! =)

Comment: El error se debe a que estas tratando de acceder a una variable del método __init__, la cual tiene la propiedad "privada" para ese método, tal como con las funciones. La linea info = NodoInfo(self.pos) no puede ser accedida por otro método a menos que la cambies por self.info = NodoInfo(self.pos). Y en el método getInfo return str(info.getTitulo()) cambiarlo por return str(self.info.getTitulo())

Comment: Debes hacer que `info` sea un atributo de instancia como haces con `pos`, `self.info = NodoInfo(self.pos)` en el `__init__` y después `str(self.info.getTitulo())`. Exactamente lo mismo para `elemento`... Ahora mismo son variables definidas en el `__init__` cuyo ámbito se restringe a ese método por lo que son inaccesibles desde fuera y dejando de existir nada más inicializada la clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias! =D